# Correct PowerShell syntax for XML Node Loop value change

Tags: powershell

I have another question.  I have an XML document that I would like to update a couple of nodes.  I'm looking to copy/clone the device name node to a new node.  For a more of an understanding here is the sample XML document:

```
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Enclave id="OLD">
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-GooD</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
    </Enclave>
</Configuration>
```

Here is what I'm trying to get to:

```
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Enclave id="OLD">
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-GooD</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <cert>
              <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
            </cert>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <cert>
              <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
            </cert>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
    </Enclave>
</Configuration>
```

Here is my code:

```
$LoadType = "OLD"
$FileName = "C:\name.xml" 
[xml]$FileOriginal = Get-Content $FileName
$Pattern = $FileOriginal.SelectNodes("/Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]")

foreach($Pat in $Pattern) {
    $device = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("//Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]")
    $devicename = $device.name;
    $name = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('name')

    foreach($name in $device) {
    $devicename = $device.name;
    $name = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('name')
    $name.InnerText = "$devicename"
    }

    $cert = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('cert')

    $cert.AppendChild($name)

    $Pat.InsertAfter( $cert, $Pat.SelectSingleNode('vlan') ) 

}

$FileOriginal.Save($FileName)
```

Here was the result:

```
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Enclave id="OLD">
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-GooD</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <cert>
              <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
            </cert>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
        <device>
            <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
            <type>VoIP</type>
            <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
            <cert>
              <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
            </cert>
            <inform>PEM</inform>
            <outform>PEM</outform>
            <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
        </device>
    </Enclave>
</Configuration>
```

I tried to accomplish this through a foreach syntax but I don't know or think thats the correct approach.  I also tried a different approach in using the CloneNode cmdlet but I couldn't get that to work either.  Anyone have an idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is trying to do too much. Some minor simplification should make it work as desired:

```
$LoadType = "OLD"
$FileName = "c:\name.xml" 
[xml]$FileOriginal = Get-Content $FileName
$Pattern = $FileOriginal.SelectNodes("/Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]")

foreach($Pat in $Pattern) {
    # new name node
    $name = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('name')
    # set node text to the current device name
    $name.InnerText = $Pat.name
    # new cert node
    $cert = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('cert')
    # add name node as child of cert node
    $cert.AppendChild($name)
    # insert new cert node after current device's vlan node
    $Pat.InsertAfter( $cert, $Pat.SelectSingleNode('vlan') ) 

}

$FileOriginal.Save($FileName)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It worked.  I need to go back and study exactly where my logic wasn't correct.  Thanks again.

Comment: Since `$Pattern` already selected device nodes, the `foreach ($pat in $pattern)` made `$pat` be each single device. You did not need to do another `foreach`. So `$device = $pat` would have been what you wanted theoretically.